# Android: makeSceneTransition for more than one shared elements

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

I have been trying to implement animation transition on more than one shared elements using the sample example showed on the android site

```
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
    Pair.create(view1, "agreedName1"),
    Pair.create(view2, "agreedName2"));
```

but when I try to implement this code on my example application in the Eclipse IDE it says

```
The method makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, View, String) in the type ActivityOptions is not applicable for the arguments (MyActivity, Pair<View,String>, Pair<View,String>)
```

I could use some help there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across the same issue. In my case I've imported

```
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
```

instead of

```
import android.util.Pair;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Case, I was trying to pass `imageView` and `linearLayout`, whereas the method was expecting `Views`.

So I did, `View view1 = imageView;`
and `View view2 = linearLayout`.
and passed them to the method.